# While loop in a c++ Function

Tags: c++

I’m trying to do a while loop in c++ 
When i come to the loop it says Program Stopped Working I don’t know why .

```
void addNode(string name, string emil)
{
    node * temp = new node;
    NumberNode *tmp=NULL;
    string num;
    string z ="0" ;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->email = emil;
    while (num != z)
    {
        cout << "Enter your numbers : ";
        cin >> num;
        tmp->Number = num;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }


    temp->next = start;
    start = temp;
}
```

Comment: You could at least make the effort to properly name your variables. Having a variable named `tmp` and another one named `temp` shows a total lack of imagination to come with useful variable names. Also, your should spell `emil` correctly. If you are so careless, you will only write code that is hard to read and maintain. **Too much laziness and programming does not works well together.**

Answer (score 3):

You're obviously dereferencing a null pointer:

You initialize `tmp` to `NULL`.

```
NumberNode *tmp=NULL;
```

and dereference it here:

```
tmp->Number = num;
```